# Postgres: one query with multiple JOINs vs multiple queries

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis

I am working on Posrgres 9.6 with PostGIS 2.3, hosted on AWS RDS. I'm trying to optimize some geo-radius queries for data that comes from different tables.

I'm considering two approaches: single query with multiple joins or two separate but simpler queries.

---

At a high level, and simplifying the structure, my schema is:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;


CREATE TABLE addresses (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    latitude double precision,
    longitude double precision,
    line1 character varying NOT NULL,
    "position" geography(Point,4326),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_srid CHECK ((st_srid("position") = 4326))
);

CREATE INDEX index_addresses_on_position ON addresses USING gist ("position");

CREATE TABLE locations (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    uuid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    address_id bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE shops (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    location_id bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE inventories (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    shop_id bigint NOT NULL,
    status character varying NOT NULL
);
```

The `addresses` table holds the geographical data. The `position` column is calculated from the lat-lng columns when the rows are inserted or updated.

Each `address` is associated to one `location`.

Each `address` may have many `shops`, and each `shop` will have one `inventory`.

I've omitted them for brevity, but all the tables have the proper foreign key constraints and btree indexes on the reference columns.

The tables have a few hundreds of thousands of rows.

---

With that in place, my main use case can be satisfied by this single query, which searches for `addresses` within 1000 meters from a central geographical point (`10.0, 10.0`) and returns data from all the tables:

```
SELECT
    s.id AS shop_id,
    s.name AS shop_name,
    i.status AS inventory_status,
    l.uuid AS location_uuid,
    a.line1 AS addr_line,
    a.latitude AS lat,
    a.longitude AS lng
FROM addresses a
JOIN locations l ON l.address_id = a.id
JOIN shops s ON s.location_id = l.id
JOIN inventories i ON i.shop_id = s.id
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    a.position,                             -- the position of each address
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(10.0, 10.0), 4326), -- the center of the circle
    1000,                                   -- radius distance in meters
    true
);
```

This query works, and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows that it does correctly use the `GIST` index.

However, I could also split this query in two and manage the intermediate results in the application layer. For example, this works too:

```
--- only search for the addresses
SELECT
    a.id as addr_id,
    a.line1 AS addr_line,
    a.latitude AS lat,
    a.longitude AS lng
FROM addresses a
WHERE ST_DWithin(
    a.position,                             -- the position of each address
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(10.0, 10.0), 4326), -- the center of the circle
    1000,                                   -- radius distance in meters
    true
);

--- get the rest of the data
SELECT
    s.id AS shop_id,
    s.name AS shop_name,
    i.status AS inventory_status,
    l.id AS location_id,
    l.uuid AS location_uuid
FROM locations l
JOIN shops s ON s.location_id = l.id
JOIN inventories i ON i.shop_id = s.id
WHERE
    l.address_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  -- potentially thousands of values
;
```

where the values in `l.address_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` come from the first query.

---

The query plans for the two split queries look simpler than the first one's, but I wonder if that in itself means that the second solution is better.

I know that inner joins are pretty well optimized, and that a single round-trip to the DB would be preferable.

What about memory usage? Or resource contention on the tables? (e.g. locks)

Comment: In the first query, you dont *need* to select the a.xxx fields from the adresses table (and it can be moved to an in() or exists() subquery (or a CTE)) and: `potentially thousands of values`  is a showstopper.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, I thought that `potentially thousands` would be an issue. Ideally I'd actually express that as `VALUES (1), (2), ...` instead, although having thousands still makes me unhappy. I'm not sure what you mean with the first part of the comment though. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I (re-)combined your second code into a single query, using `IN(...)`:

---

```
--- get the rest of the data
SELECT
    s.id AS shop_id,
    s.name AS shop_name,
    i.status AS inventory_status,
    l.id AS location_id,
    l.uuid AS location_uuid
FROM locations l
JOIN shops s ON s.location_id = l.id
JOIN inventories i ON i.shop_id = s.id
WHERE l.address_id IN ( --- only search for the addresses
        SELECT a.id
        FROM addresses a
        WHERE ST_DWithin(a.position, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(10.0, 10.0), 4326), 1000 true)
        );
```

---

Or, similarly ,using `EXISTS(...)`:

---

```
--- get the rest of the data
SELECT
    s.id AS shop_id,
    s.name AS shop_name,
    i.status AS inventory_status,
    l.id AS location_id,
    l.uuid AS location_uuid
FROM locations l
JOIN shops s ON s.location_id = l.id
JOIN inventories i ON i.shop_id = s.id
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * --- only search for the addresses
        FROM addresses a
        WHERE a.id = l.address_id 
        AND ST_DWithin( a.position, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(10.0, 10.0), 4326), 1000, true)
        );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the variants. Just to be sure that I understand: performance-wise, would these still be preferable to my two separate queries?

Comment: Unfortunately, I actually need these address fields in my result set: `line1, latitude, longitude`, so I don't think that your variants would satisfy my use case.

Comment: Well: then select them. Either using your original query, or separately.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know my original queries work. This question was about the performance implications of the two approaches. Still, thanks for the suggestions.